# Unable to install Flutter on my windows machine

Tags: flutter

I am struggling in configuring Flutter on my windows laptop. Is Flutter supported on windows.

Comment: Windows is currently not supported, which is mentioned on the [Flutter Setup page](https://flutter.io/setup/): "Operating Systems: Mac or Linux (64-bit). Windows support is in progress"

Comment: Window is now supported, see https://flutter.io/setup-windows/.

Answer (score 1):

Windows support is work in progress https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/138

See also https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+windows+label%3A%22%E2%9D%96+platform-windows%22

Answer (score 1):

Windows is now a supported OS for Flutter development. Install details here: https://flutter.io/setup-windows/.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter now supports windows for development and can be installed using the guide mentioned in flutter docs https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows ,

if you still face issue installing the flutter sdk,I recommend you reading my answer for [flutter doctor doesn't work on neither Command Prompt or PowerShell window?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53465355/8253662)