# Flutter commands not working in Windows command prompt

Tags: flutter

I've installed Flutter latest version by manually downloading from flutter.io and configured PATH in System Environments Variable.

My installation path is C:\src\flutter I've set the path to C:\src\flutter\bin, when i run the 'flutter doctor' command it throws

> 'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.
>
> 'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.
>   Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.

But it runs throws flutter .bat terminal. My git is working properly too.

I tried re-starting my PC, Still no luck.

Comment: Seems like the flutter command works, but is unable find git. what happens when you run "git" from a normal cmd window?

Comment: @boformer normal git commands just works fine

Comment: hmmm. all you can do is follow the steps again, reinstall git and other required software

Comment: @bofomer I repeated same stpes twice, still didn't work. Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I had been facing a similar issue for a while,and  after about half an hour playing around with it I was able to get the flutter command running, what I did was

- uninstalled and then reinstalled git (**Note: check this third option while installation so that it gets added to environment variable**)

[image: check for environment variable]

- and changed the location of flutter SDK from Downloads to  Documents.
- and separately added the path of SDK to the environment variable also make sure you have added the path of git and system32 as I did in the image.

this is How my environment variable looks, Note that I have moved SDK path to the top.

[image]

In case you would like to see my answer on flutter installation check out this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53465355/8253662

Answer (score 0):

Try Running your command prompt as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Try Running your command prompt as administrator.
I think most of the problems is related to permission .
if you done all the instructions in the documentation
then probably the problem is related to the permission of your windows.
iv faced this problem but then i ran cmd.exe as administrator
you will find it in system 32