# How to locate the exact place where the vscode extensions are placed?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I can't create a new flutter project when i already installed **flutter** and **dart** extentions on my vscode in windows 10 (64 bits).

[image: vscode]

Please help to solve my problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49609889/flutter-doctor-doesnt-work-on-neither-command-prompt-or-powershell-window

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path to the `flutter/bin` folder to your `PATH` environment variable and then restart.

FWIW, you can also run the `Flutter: New Project` command from the VS Code command palette rather than running it yourself through the terminal. This will do more for you :-)