# why i cannot run any flutter project?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I am using android studio to run flutter project, now i can not run any project and i get the same error every time:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
     platforms;android-29 Android SDK Platform 29
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 29s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seem you did not accepted all licences after install.
Try to run this:

> flutter doctor --android-licenses

and then press `y` every time it ask, to accept the licence

seems like [duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49762939/4684512)

Comment: where can i run this? i cant run it in terminal

Comment: in Android studio at the bottom you can open "terminal" tab and try it there

Comment: to correct myself, it must be run in terminal which knows a valid flutter path and flutter command

Comment: yes i know i should run it in therminal, but i cant, it keep telling                             
 'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: that means you have not setup env path to flutter. Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53465355/4684512 . I cannot guide you on this, since I don't have windows :/

Comment: it actualy works, after i run flutter doctor. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you should delete config Android studio folder and reinstall that whit all requirements.

C:\Users[your name folder]

[image]